# Android Room Advanced Query with list and multiple conditions

Tags: android, android-room

i have a query like this

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE type IN(:types) AND selection = 0 ORDER BY timestamp DESC")
```

my problem is that i have one type in my type list lets say it's type=4 for which i want selection = 1.
Is it possible to get the results in one query and how should the query look like?

Comment: Off the cuff, `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (type IN(:types) AND selection = 0) OR (type = 4 AND selection = 1) ORDER BY timestamp DESC`, where `types` should not contain `4` unless you want both `selection = 0` and `selection = 1` results for that type.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yeah that is my problem. The types list can contain type 4 but for type 4 for i want only results with selection = 1 and for the other types in the list results with selection = 0.